# How do I replace outbound link URLs in a PDF document, using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF document with some external links.

I'd like to parse the document, replace the destination of the links then close (and serve) the PDF document, all using PHP

I know I can do this with PDFLib but I don't want to incur this cost.

I could re-write the document with FPDF or DomPDF, but some of these PDFs are quite complex so this would be a major time investment.

Surely there must be a way to do this directly to PDF docs, using native PHP?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a text/hyperlink changer class for PHP. The closest products, like [pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/), only does higher-level stuff like merging, splitting and applying watermarks.

Changing a pdf is much more difficult than generating it, so you need to use a pdf editor like [Nitro PDF](http://www.nitropdf.com/professional/edit-pdf.htm) (untested), or why not Acrobat/Illustrator/InDesign.

If you must use PHP, regenerating the PDF:s with one of the free classes seems to be your best choice. I like FPDF very much, it gets my recommendation. If you decide to use it, check out [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) as well, it can use existing PDF files as a template, maybe it will help you. Good luck!